# What would a human genetically modified to thrive in low gravity look like?

Tags: biology, space, gravity, genetic-engineering

Really just what the title says. If a human was genetically reengineered (assume super-futuristic-magical level genetic engineering capabilities) for microgravity, what would be some likely changes? The only bounds I have are that they would retain basic human form, I.e. arms, legs, and a head. Would bone structure change at all? Could any improvements be made without compromising the body’s fitness in Earth’s higher gravity?

Edit: Comments have asked for more specifics on what the humans would be doing. A lot of the modifications would be around just living in low gravity without atrophy or decay, if that’s possible; for example, astronauts on the ISS have reported loss of vision and potential harm of radiation while in space. Some stuff would be mobility-based, like being able to move around in low gravity easier or more efficiently, preferably on a rocky or dusty lunar surface. These people frequently move around in EVA suits for the better part of the day, so they won’t always be in a fully pressurized or radiation-sealed environment. As far as what they do, some of them are soldiers, some of them are scientists, and the rest are clergy (think NASA base turned theocratic cult). I guess I’m just asking for ways humans could change in general to survive better on the moon.

Comment: Look like? Just appearance? What is wrong with 100% the same, no visible changes? What kind of improovement you are looking for - reactive propulsion? Sticky hands? Why do you expect there is an answer to your q with its current form? Isn't an answer just a list of what one would like to have,  like that reactive fusion antimater propulsion I mention.

Comment: You could draw inspiration from Lois McMaster Bujold's quaddie race from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_Free .  Among other genetically engineered zero-g adaptations, quaddies were designed to have arms where their legs should be, giving them a total of four arms (hence the name), which made them quite adept at their purpose, being zero-g construction workers.

Comment: MolbOrg Humans evolved in much higher gravity than I mean in this scenario, so we don’t do well in low-gravity environments. There are plenty of videos of Apollo astronauts struggling even to walk on the moon. My question is if a human could be genetically engineered to fix this, I.e. I would imagine a lower center of mass/shorter legs would help a human keep balanced, or homeostasis could be altered to adapt to lower temperatures and pressures, or resistance to radiation could be improved, etc. Just seeing if people had more ideas

Comment: GrumpyYoungMan thanks! Gripping arms/legs do seem useful without much friction. I’ll give that article a look.

Comment: Add that information from comment to body of q - it would be an improvement to a q. As offtopic purely curiosity - why genetic engenering and not technology?

Comment: But to do what? If they're just going to be sitting doing paperwork at a desk, why any different? If they're engineers, then four hands would be useful, if long-distance couriers, then four long limbs for locomotion might fit. Could you [edit] to add a few details about the context? Without an edit, it's too broad to answer.

Comment: @MolbOrg we don't know the context of this question, maybe this genetic change is needed to e.g. colonize an asteroid for some reason.. or allow a local community to mine an asteroid.. in that case people could be in space for decades, large part of their life. The Space Station crew does not need genetic changes, because they're living in space for less than a year.. and also, they use instruments and living space designed for human body shape. Size is a limitation too, if you could have a smaller body size that would make it easier.

Comment: If the fix you want is just to make normal humans, but with less trouble with low/no gravity, then fixes would be cosmetic. Decouple the biology from gravity, so muscle mass is less dependent on exercise, Digestion is more muscled and less settling, bone strength doesn't need resistance, balance/fall sensor are decouple from physical responses (but still work), blood vessels tolerate  wider pressure ranges/ranges, etc. Tiny stuff, but thousands of tiny changes and a few that are big but have no visible manifestations.

Comment: A Rogue Ant I edited it, sorry for lack of context ;)

Comment: MolbOrg Good question, I was actually thinking of using technological modifications (I.e. prosthetics, mech suits, etc.) for more specific tasks, but I wanted to know if there were any general changes all humans would receive beforehand. I was thinking, for example, all of these humans would have been genetically modified to resist cancer from radiation. That wouldn’t really make them look different I don’t think but pretty much everyone would be modified that way.

Comment: DWKraus thanks, that was really the question I was trying to ask. I was hoping there would be some cool looking but scientifically justifiable cosmetic changes lol

Comment: Lack of context is what put me in closing camp, u made edit, I cast reopen. If you looking for scientifically justified visual changes - idk, in my opinion it would be better to ask it directly, not wrapping it in future mumbo yumbo - yep it a lottery but maybe someone did hold such answer and was just waiting for such q. All genetic engenering q's have many problems, kne of whihc is - it does not solve character immediate problems, it may be useful for descendants. Or if it like plastic surgery - it advanced tech which it better at solving all those problems than a fragile meat.

Comment: Another problem with gen stuff and looks is - whatever problem can be solved by it can be solved without changing external appearance(maybe even always, but for simplicity kinda always).  So you handwave difference, handwave problem and solution etc - there is not that much to do for rational deduction. Another problem is questionable efficiency, and most important I reconfigure my suit in less than a minute(this one or wear another one) for it to fit current specific conditions and task - can one do so with genmod - there is no way for it by definition Tech is switchable by flick of a finger

Comment: As I said ask directly for the pairs of visual differences and plausible scientific reasoning - it may be a better way and sure more useful way for other potencial authors - reusabilty of such q and A's will be better. And such q would make more sense, because answer to current one is any and none. Try ask/formulate a different one and abandon this one, still, do not forget some context, do not rely on telepathy - advice is imho and asis

Comment: It's worth noting that, if humans have the ability to freely redesign their genome, they will also inevitably use it to make themselves more attractive (to each other). Their beauty standards will be different from ours, to accommodate the functional needs of life in microgravity, but within and atop those constraints I'd expect to see quite a lot of purely aesthetic/cosmetic changes. I'd expect them to have much bigger eyes (function _and_ beauty), and no unpleasant skin conditions.

Comment: Are you talking about *low* gravity (like on the moon) or *no* gravity (spaceship-dwellers)?  The question isn't quite clear and the answers may be very different.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess I’m just asking for ways humans could change in general to survive better *on the moon*.

Form follow function. Assuming breathable atmosphere from the majority of lifetime spent inside - at least 2/3 of it during active ages, almost all of it during childhood and retirement.

Thinner skeleton, probably longer bones. Weaker muscles - because more of them is a waste. On that note, weaker hearts - no need to fight gravity that much - but about the same volume (the nutrient transport and oxygenation needs is about the same, the brain will have its energy or else).

Gait switched to resemble a kangaroo jumping - more energetically economic that way in lower gravity. Shorter legs, though, with the current leg lengths you lose finer control jumping over distances (overshooting). Probably higher ceiling, to accommodate for this style of walking.

Falling over larger heights isn't that dangerous, so I suspect the architecture will evolve towards higher stair steps. Higher falling distances and longer time spent in free fall (jumping is free fall) will allow more time to get unbalanced or slightly improper attitude at landing. I suspect a set of movements of the [cat righting reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_righting_reflex) nature will become a muscle-learned habit the toddler will adjust before even walking. In time, those with a more mobile backbone and flexible joins will be at advantage, so expect to see joint flexibility as an evolutionary trait.

> Could any improvements be made without compromising the body’s fitness in Earth’s higher gravity?

Nope, Earth gravity will kill them in short time. Their backbone first - better fit for mobility and less for weight, their weaker sinews that keep their organs in place, their brain used to the specific of locomotion in lower gravity causing frequent accidents (with a thinner skeleton in higher gravity). Prepare to have them living in mobile bath tubs while visiting Earth, the water pressure and buoyancy helping them survive.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: below scenario would not require magic. Maybe it can be done easily.. certain cettle breeds have already been bred back to restore ancestor size and strength. I'm not sure about the implications for humans, such as brain size, so let's suppose there is genetic engineering able to do a selective mix of properties..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breeding_back

**Ape**

With advanced generic engineering at hand, consider integrating ape DNA to reconstruct body size, limbs and motoric control as found in bonobo and chimpansee (in case of back-breeding: our common ancestors), featuring gripping feet, with short, jumping legs and relatively long arms. Being able to go forward jumping and grabbing obstacles is what apes do best.

Of course, you'd want to preserve the mental capabilties of the human cortex, the gene swap would need to be partial.. but also in the brain, there are some nice features in apes that would be handy in space. Balance involving center of gravity, a sense for rotation, the accurate muscle control when grabbing.. these ape-properties would come in handy when you move around freely in zero-gravity circumstances.

Comment: Becoming ape-like is cool concept, especially for zero gravity where yanking yourself around is more crucial. I might implement that. Farting to get around would be really funny but I figure an EVA jetpack is probably more efficient lol

Comment: jet packs ? you know how much these things cost ? (lol ;) I've removed the farting part.. guess I got downvoted for it )

Answer (score 0):

If your people live in both environments it would be pretty great to be able to adjust their centre of gravity and maybe even their weight to whatever environment they are currently in, which could be done by an ability to retain water in different areas of the body for example, making them and yourself heavier or lighter depending on the environment. The water storage could also be used in temperature regulation.

Speaking of water, maybe take inspiration from animals living in the oceans, maybe the solution is not (solely) managing to walk properly but controlling the floating around better.

An ability to use suction to hold onto the ground or objects, starfish style, would come handy with both strategies though.

Comment: I didn’t even think of changing center of gravity, but that sounds really useful, actually. I thought of using a suction (or claws) to hold onto stuff, but figured if the astronaut was going to be wearing a space suit anyways I’d just leave that to the suit itself. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

(assume super-futuristic-magical level genetic engineering capabilities)

Ok, the humans look like whatever they want to look like. Mostly that's a normalish but very attractive human. (Whatever their beauty standards are). But one of the crew would prefer to be a writhing ball of tentacles and that's ok too.

At this stage, the bones degrading from lack of use is just trivially not going to happen.
For high G environments there are some restrictions, depending on how high G. You can look human but have greatly enhanced muscles and still have no problem walking around in 10G. But some of the spindlier designs favoured by the low G folks can't work there. Of course, these folks change their genes as easily as their jeans. If they aren't expecting to be in a high G environment today, they might use a body plan that is designed for whatever they are doing in low G. For really high G or other extreme environments, there are specialized body plans, but you wouldn't use them unless you intended to go into those environments.

Answer (score 0):

## Heavy and Robust

It seems like a thin, lightweight form would be useful for these humans, and it would be if not for the fact that humans have to move

As far as my research has found, spacesuits have a mass of around 130kg. This means, factoring in human body mass, that the weight, and therefore normal force, on real moonwalkers' feet is around 320N, which is over 3x the normal force for a regular human on the moon, and much higher than a more gracile species

Why does this matter? Because of friction: Frictional force is the Coefficient of Friction multiplied by the normal force. Hence, a low normal force implies low friction, which is not conducive to getting around

Your humans will need to be at least 200kg in mass to get around, assuming similar grip to spacesuit boots. If they have less grip, they'll need to be heavier to compensate

Most of this extra weight should be concentrated in the torso, as it moves the least. The legs should also have a portion of this weight, both to lower the centre of mass for balance, and to make sure the legs are strong enough to carry the weight comfortably on Earth. The arms would have similar weigh to the legs, as they serve the purpose of balancing the body as the legs move

Apart from that, there are other changes that must be made: Specifically, the excretory parts and the inner ear, alongside other organs that sense weight, will have to be more sensitive in the reduced gravity of the moon. This will mean that on Earth, among other effects, they will relieve themselves 6 times as often as on the moon